# Magento checkout billing information

Tags: magento

In my module, I want to know when the user had entered their billing and shipping information. I have two events that I listen for:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShipping
```

When going through the Magento one page checkout, the billing stage has a checkbox "Ship to this address". If you check this box, the shipping address entry stage is skipped and the controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShipping event does not fire.
Is there a way that my observer of the controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling event can determine whether the user checked that box or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather simple to ask it directly from shipping address object

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->getSameAsBilling();
```